# Ruby - Merging two hashes with some keys similar

Tags: ruby, hash, key

Essentially I only want to merge the keys which appear in both hashes.
the end goal is adding or multiplying the values.

```
hash1 = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 }
hash2 = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4, "e" => 5}
{"a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 6 }
```

This worked in a sense of adding the correct values, however also returned d and e.

```
hash1.merge(hash2) { |key1, value1, value2| value1 + value2 }
#=> {"a" => 2, "b" => 4, "c" => 6, "d" => 4, "e" => 5}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: hash1.merge(hash2) do |key1, value1, value2| 
            value1 + value2
Which was kind of right apart from the fact I ended up with d and e also amongst the merge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
hash1 = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 }
hash2 = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4, "e" => 5}


(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).map{ |key| [key, hash1[key] + hash2[key]]}.to_h
 => {"a"=>2, "b"=>4, "c"=>6}
```

Comment: you can just `(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).to_h{ |key| [key, hash1[key] + hash2[key]]}`

Answer (score 2):

You could determine the common [`keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#keys-method) via [`&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#26-method):

```
keys = hash1.keys & hash2.keys
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and then use [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#slice-method) before `merge`:

```
hash1.slice(*keys).merge(hash2.slice(*keys)) { |k, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
#=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>4, "c"=>6}
```

In your example, the result is equivalent to merging the keys from `hash2` that also exist in `hash1` which could be written as:

```
hash1.merge(hash2.slice(*hash1.keys)) { |k, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
#=> {"a"=>2, "b"=>4, "c"=>6}
```

This however only works if `hash1` defines the common keys.